# How to get Large Model Property using GetModelviewProperties API in C#

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to get large model property using 'GetModelviewProperties' API in C#.
(the model is translated svf2 format)

I faced the problem and got an error.

Error Message is

```
Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling GetModelviewProperties: 
{"diagnostic":"Property Database is too large under this URN"}'
```

Do you have an IDEA for solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) states, there's a `forceget` URL query parameter that can be set to:

- `true`: Forcibly gets large resources even if they exceed the expected maximum size (20 MB). If the resource is larger than 800 MB, the server behaves as though forceget is false. In such a case, use the objectid query string parameter to download resources by Object ID.
- `false`: (Default) Does not get resources if they exceed the expected maximum size (20 MB).

Another option would be to getting the properties using one of the other formats, and not JSON. Please refer to this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately i already tried `forceget` option, but it doesn't works.
Another option that you had suggested is only available 'svf' format? is it work on 'svf2' format?
And Can you tell me the other option?

Comment: The options mentioned in the blog post should work for SVF2 as well, because SVF2 is created by post-processing SVF.